# Geting value from radio input and setting it to variable

Tags: jquery, button, input, radio-button

I have few divs with text inputs and few divs with radio type inputs. I tried using jquery to assign the values from these inputs to certain variables when the button is clicked, but it just don`t seem to work (`echo $number_value`or`echo $second_form_value` shows nothing)

**The input part:**

```
     <div id="first_div">
    <form name="first_form" action="">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="first_form" id="first_form_label">Some text for the user</label>
        <input type="number" name="number_info" id="number_info" size="7" value="" class="text-input" />
        <br />
        <label class="error" for="first_form" id="first_form_error">Error alert</label>
        <br />
        <input type="button" name="value" class="button" id="first_form_button" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>




<div id="second_div">
    <form name="second_form" action="">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="second_form" id="second_form_label">Some text for the user</label><br />
        <input type="radio" name="second_form_info" id="second_form_A"  value="A" class="text-input" />           
        <label for="A">Choose A</label><br />

        <input type="radio" name="second_form_info" id="second_form_B"  value="B" class="text-input" />
        <label for="B">Choose B</label>
        <br />
        <label class="error" for="second_form" id="second_form_error">Error alert</label>
        <br />
        <input type="button" name="value" class="button" id="second_form_button" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

**And the jquery part:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
```

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$('#first_form_button').click(function(){
$("#number_info").on("keyup change", function() {
var number_value =  $('#number_info').val();
});
$('#first_div').hide();
$('#second_div').show();
```

});

```
$('#second_form_button').click(function(){
$("#second_form_info").on("keyup change", function() {
var second_form_value =  $('#input[name$='second_form_info']').val();
});
$('#first_div').hide();
```

});

can somebody point out what is fundamentally flawed in it?

Answer (score 0):

You are waiting to bind your handlers for `keyup` and `change` until you click on the buttons within the form. Put those handlers outside the `click` function. The variable you are setting within the `.change` handler is also local to that handler, so accessing it outside wont be possible.

```
$("#second_form_info").on("keyup change", function() {
    var second_form_value =  $('#input[name$='second_form_info']').val();
});

$('#second_form_button').click(function(){
    $('#first_div').hide();
});
```

Comment: so for example, if I wanted to use that variable outside the handler (for sending it to MySQL), it would not be possible?

Comment: It would be, you would just need to use a more accessible variable (declare it outside the handler) -- or just grab the value when you want to send it back to SQL

Comment: good man tymeJV, could you show (or link) to example how could this be declared outside the handler?